# Django bulk_create function example

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to understand bulk_create in Django

This was my original query I'm trying to convert:

```
for e in q:
    msg = Message.objects.create(
        recipient_number=e.mobile,
        content=batch.content,
        sender=e.contact_owner,
        billee=batch.user,
        sender_name=batch.sender_name
    )
```

Does that mean doing the following (below) will loop and create all the entries first then hit the database? Is this right?

```
msg = Message.objects.bulk_create({
    Message (
        recipient_number=e.mobile,
        content=batch.content,
        sender=e.contact_owner,
        billee=batch.user,
        sender_name=batch.sender_name
    ),
})
```

Comment: You are almost there. Do not create the objects in the loop. Just do `Message(...)` instead of `Message.objects.create(...)` - It would not trigger a database call. Put that into a list, and pass that list into `bulk_create`

Answer (score 63, accepted):

The second code in the question create a single object, because it pass a set with a Message object.

To create multiple objects, pass multiple Message objects to bulk_create. For example:

```
objs = [
    Message(
        recipient_number=e.mobile,
        content=batch.content,
        sender=e.contact_owner,
        billee=batch.user,
        sender_name=batch.sender_name
    )
    for e in q
]
msg = Message.objects.bulk_create(objs)
```

Comment: What if I have a million objects? Would this matter?

Comment: If you have the processing capabilities to handle 1MM objects, then sure

Comment: It it CPU or Memory out of interest?

Comment: @User7, It will consume memory to hold 1M objects (1M * a size of `Message` object). CPU usage would be similar to `create` version. I/O usage will be much less than `create` version.

Comment: How do you get around IntegrityError for duplicates?

Comment: @radtek, `try: ... except IntegrityError`? If you mean you want to update if record is already there: `bulk_create` is not tool for such purpose as the name suggest. You'd better find dbms-specific functionality: for example, [REPLACE INTO ...](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) for MySQL, ...

Comment: Yeah thats what I thought, its the only way to do mass insert really because if you try except IntegrityError nothing goes in. You can use psycopg2 within django like this example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20747117/django-over-postgresql-using-raw-sql-insert-with-returning-statement-not-workin

Comment: In order to avoid memory issues, you could use an generator function for creating the list on the fly.

Comment: I'd like to know the difference between looping to create objects and bulk creating objects. Does it have something to do with performance? Which one is more acceptable and why? Thanks.

Comment: @SugarTang, See [`queryset.bulk_create` - QuerySet API Reference](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/querysets/#bulk-create)

Comment: is there is similar bulk_delete api ?

Comment: @Amistad, Depending on filter condition, `QuerySet.delete()` can delete multiple rows at once.

Comment: accessing e.key will throw AttributeError, e['key'] worked for me.

Comment: @HarvindarSinghGarcha, It depends on what you're iterating. `e.key` came from OP's code.

Comment: Just wanted to say this is a beautifully coded/formatted pythonic solution!

Answer (score 2):

Simple, just do this:

```
class Entry(models.Model):
    blog = models.ForeignKey(Blog, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    headline = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    body_text = models.TextField()
    pub_date = models.DateField()
    mod_date = models.DateField()
```

Now, to Bulk Create

```
Entry.objects.bulk_create([
        Entry(headline='This is a test'),
        Entry(headline='This is only a test'),
 ])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
name = request.data.get('name')
period = request.data.get('period')
email = request.data.get('email')
prefix = request.data.get('prefix')
bulk_number = int(request.data.get('bulk_number'))

bulk_list = list()
for _ in range(bulk_number):
    code = code_prefix + uuid.uuid4().hex.upper()
    bulk_list.append(
        DjangoModel(name=name, code=code, period=period, user=email))

bulk_msj = DjangoModel.objects.bulk_create(bulk_list)
```