# Django over Postgresql: using raw sql insert with returning statement not working

Tags: sql, django, insert

Using Postgresql 9.3 + PostGIS with django, I'm trying to enter a record to my table and return the given id like so

```
def join(request):
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    id = cursor.execute("insert into table1 values(DEFAULT, 'temp', null,-4, null,null, null, null, DEFAULT, 1,null,DEFAULT,DEFAULT, null) returning id")
    transaction.set_dirty()

    return HttpResponse(id)
```

this returns `None`, how can i get the id that is returned from the sql query

Answer (score 2):

```
from django.db import connection, transaction

def join(request):
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    id = cursor.execute("insert into table1 values(DEFAULT, 'temp', null,-4, null,null, null, null, DEFAULT, 1,null,DEFAULT,DEFAULT, null)")
    transaction.set_dirty()
    last_id = connection.insert_id()
    return HttpResponse(str(last_id))
```

Comment: I'm getting an error `global name 'string' is not defined` also if i print last_id i get 0

Comment: Sorry about that. Fixed. Use `str`

Comment: Edited again, to use the connection object to get the id

Comment: now i'm getting this error: 'DatabaseWrapper' object has no attribute 'insert_id'

Answer (score 0):

What is your database backend? If you use sqlite3,

```
def join(request):
    from django.db import connection, transaction
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute("insert into table1 values(DEFAULT, 'temp', null,-4, null,null, null, null, DEFAULT, 1,null,DEFAULT,DEFAULT, null)")
    cursor.execute("SELECT last_insert_rowid() FROM table1")
    id = cursor.fetchone()[0]
    transaction.set_dirty()

    return HttpResponse(id)
```