# (1054, "Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'") Django bulk_create

Tags: python, mysql, django, mysql-python

I am getting the following error when trying to insert data using Django's bulk_create method. It doesn't happen for all data being inserted.

(1054, "Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'")

I don't really understand where the 'nan' is coming from, as I explicitly declare all my fields here.

I am trying to insert a large amount of objects at a time to the database (around 10,000 or more)

My code is as follows, where observation is another object, TemporaryPhotometry is the model being used:

```
    # With thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383471/django-bulk-create-function-example for the
    # example on how to use the bulk_create function so we don't thrash the DB

    phot_objects = [
        TemporaryPhotometry(
            calibrated_magnitude=function_to_make_calibrated_magnitude(),
            calibrated_error=uncertainty_stars[i],
            magnitude_rms_error=mage_2[i],
            x=x_2[i],
            y=y_2[i],
            alpha_j2000=ra_2[i],
            delta_j2000=de_2[i],
            fwhm_world=fwhm_2[i],
            flags=flag_2[i],
            magnitude=mag_2[i],
            observation=observation,
        )
        for i in range(0, len(num_2))
    ]

    TemporaryPhotometry.objects.bulk_create(phot_objects)
```

I would greatly appreciate any help with solving this issue. Thank you.

The full stack trace is the following:

```
File "/var/www/image_processing/analysis/utils/calibration.py" in do_calibration
  545.         TemporaryPhotometry.objects.bulk_create(phot_objects)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/manager.py" in manager_method
  85.                 return getattr(self.get_queryset(), name)(*args, **kwargs)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in bulk_create
  443.                 ids = self._batched_insert(objs_without_pk, fields, batch_size)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _batched_insert
  1099.                 self._insert(item, fields=fields, using=self.db)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py" in _insert
  1076.         return query.get_compiler(using=using).execute_sql(return_id)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py" in execute_sql
  1099.                 cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/utils.py" in __exit__
  94.                 six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py" in execute
  65.                 return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/django/db/backends/mysql/base.py" in execute
  101.             return self.cursor.execute(query, args)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/cursors.py" in execute
  205.             self.errorhandler(self, exc, value)

File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py" in defaulterrorhandler
  36.     raise errorclass, errorvalue

Exception Type: OperationalError at /process/calibration/624/
Exception Value: (1054, "Unknown column 'nan' in 'field list'")
```

Comment: I'm not sure what we are dealing with, but "nan" sounds like it's not coming from django.  That is the value for None in other languages, like javascript.  Are you getting information from something outside of python?

Comment: @timmsimpkins or from pandas/numpy

Comment: Yeah the uncertainty_stars[i] etc. are NumPy arrays. Would it be these being NaN the problem then? The wording of the exception was making me think it was a column rather than actual data issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by wrapping all the NumPy arrays, such as `uncertainty_stars[i]` with the following if statement, to check if they were NaN or not.

`uncertainty_stars[i] if not numpy.isnan(uncertainty_stars[i]) else None`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a clue: In C#, "NaN" gets assigned to a double when dividing by ZERO in a calculation.
When attempting to insert this result in a Database, it returns this error.
Check your denominator before dividing.